# php check if array values are consecutive

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$dice (4,7,3,6,7)`

I need a way of checking if each of the values in that array are consecutive numbers.

Is there an easy method of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "consecutive"?

Comment: if you mean in order, just duplicate the array, sort the duplicate and compare with `==`

Comment: @fge, [Consecutive definition](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/consecutive)

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$dice = array(4,5,2,6,7);
function checkConsec($d) {
    for($i=0;$i<count($d);$i++) {
        if(isset($d[$i+1]) && $d[$i]+1 != $d[$i+1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
var_dump(checkConsec($dice)); //returns false
var_dump(checkConsec(array(4,5,6,7))); //returns true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function HasConsec($array)
{
    $res = false;
    $cb = false;
    foreach ($array as $im)
    {
        if ($cb !== false && $cb == $im)
            $res = true;
        $cb = $im + 1;
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Comment: how would I use this? `if (HasConsec($dice) =='1')` ?

Comment: if (HasConsec($dice))... the function returns a boolean

Answer (score 1):

I think this that this is what you are looking for

```
for ($c = 0; $c < count($dice); $c++){
    $next_arr_pos = $c+1;

    if ($c == (count($dice) -1)){
        $cons_check = $dice[$c];
    }
    else
    {
        $cons_check = $dice[$next_arr_pos];
        $gap_calc = $cons_check-$dice[$c];
    }

    if ($dice[$c] < $cons_check && $gap_calc == 1){

        echo 'arr_pos = '.$dice[$c].' Is consecutive with '.$cons_check.' <br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with another approach:

```php
$nums = [-1,0,1];
$nums = array_unique($nums); # optional, comment on the bottom
$range = range(min($nums), max($nums));
$diff = array_diff($range, $nums);
$isConsecutive = empty($diff) && count($nums) === count($range);
```

`$nums = array_unique($nums)` - add this if you consider arrays with duplicated numbers valid too e.g. `[-1,0,1,1]`

Answer (score 0):

However, I'm not a PHP developer and I know that the question looks very old but there is an easy algorithm which I like to share with you that can tell you if your array is consecutive or not.

Here are the steps:

- find the maximum number and the minimum number of the input array.
- apply the equation: `(max - min + 1) == array.length`.
- if true, then it is consecutive other wise false.

Comment: I just wanted to avoid looping through the input array

Comment: `array = [1,2,4,3,5,6]; (6 - 1 + 1 == array.length) == true`

Comment: Which is true as 6 -1 + 1 = 6 which equals the length of the array

Comment: But those values are not consecutive was my point. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` is an array of consecutive numbers.

Comment: but it's consecutive when sorted, that's why you are getting a true 
I found the algorithms here too: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-array-elements-are-consecutive/

Comment: This algoritm will only work with integers. Assuming we also going to have arrays which do not have only integers e.g. for this array `[-1,1,1.5,2]` the algorithm will return `true`

Comment: @micper if I'm not mistaken, that's correct because the arrey you provided here is still consecutive as 1.5 lies between 1 and 2. but if your array was `[-1,1,1.5,2, 4]` for example, that won’t return true. If I'm mistaken, I would like to get your help in writing the right algorithm

Comment: With `$ar = [1, 1, 1, 1, 5]` we have `min($ar) = 1` and `max($ar) = 5`, so `$max - $min + 1 == 5 == count($ar)`, but the numbers are not consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

1// care your RAM!

2// only valid for increments of one by one (3.02, 3.03, 3.04, ... are consecutives!)

```
$x = ARRAY(9, 999999999);       // be careful!, RAM!
$x = ARRAY(99999997, 99999998, 99999999);

function concq_N($A){
    $tmp = $A[0];
    for($i = 1; $i < count($A); ++ $i){
        ++ $tmp;
        if($tmp != $A[$i])return false;
        }
    return true;
    }

echo(concq_N($x));
```

maybe a function including `$scale_of_increment` and `$direction` will be intersting:

```
$x = ARRAY(-99999997, -99999998, -99999999);
```

is consecutive!, but my function return false xD