# How to extract sequence of numbers from array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a unordered array of numbers:

```
$ar1 = [101,4,320,1,2,3,45,46];
```

and i want to extract longest sequence of numbers in that array and put them in second array?
I have tried with **usort** and I get this:

```
Array(
[0] => 1
[1] => 2
[2] => 3
[3] => 4
[4] => 45
[5] => 46
[6] => 101
[7] => 320
[8] => 321
[9] => 323)
```

but how to extract just longest sequence (witch in this case is 1,2,3,4) and put in another array?

**UPDATE:**
Here is a code:

```
function sub($a,$b)
{
if ($a == $b)
{
    return 0;
}
return ($a<$b)? -1:1;
}

$ar1 = ["101","4","320","321","323","1","3","2","45","46"];
$ar2 = [];
usort($ar1,"sub");
print_r($ar1);
```

so i want to populate $ar2 with longest sequence in array...

Comment: What would the expected output be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8695620/php-check-if-array-values-are-consecutive)

Comment: just [1,2,3,4] in array

Comment: My initial thought would be, **you are going to have to write some code**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it:

```
$ar1 = [101,4,320,1,2,3,45,46,47];
sort($ar1);
$first = $ar1[0];//assign first (lowest) number
$i=0;
$ar2 = array(); //this array will contain all arrays of consecutive numbers
foreach($ar1 as $v){
    if($v-$first == 1){
        $ar2[$i][] = $v;
    }else{
        $i++;
        $ar2[$i] = array($v); //difference > 1, we set another array
    }
    $first = $v;
}
//now we look for the longest array
$max = 0;
$longest = array();
foreach($ar2 as $k=>$ar){
    $c = count($ar);
    if($c < $max){
        unset($ar2[$k]); //if it is not the longest, we discard it
    }else{
        $max = $c;
        $longest = $ar;
    }
}
echo"<pre>";
print_r($longest);
echo"</pre>";
```

Yields:

`Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)`

Copy, paste, run, enjoy!

Comment: I'm happy then. Will be even happier when you accept my answer :)

Comment: Thanks, also change the title - it is not extrapolation in mathematic meaning. And change whont to want.